# ASP.NET IE11, Session breaks on each page

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, session, iis

I've got an application in ASP. NET 4.5 written in C# and I'm having a problem with session in IE11 (haven't tested on other IE's).
When I run my app locally everything is fine even in IE, but when I access the deployed version (IIS 8) session breaks every time I switch a page (Checked with JS in SessionStart).
At the moment I'm out of ideas what could be the reason, maybe something with IIS settings ?

I'd be very grateful for any clue :)

Greets, Maciek

Comment: may post your code to better understand ???it is not normal.

Comment: Ok I found the reason. I had undescore ('_') in adress and this causes IE to ignore cookies (session cookie as well) ;)

Comment: good news:) i' happy that you fixed your issue